# Thymeleaf error validation: spring boot starter validation always displaying errors

Tags: spring, validation, thymeleaf, conditional-rendering

**build.gradle** file

```
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'
        runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
        implementation 'io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60:3.1.1'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '3.0.1'
    }
```

**UserModel** file

```java
    
    import jakarta.persistence.*;
    import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
    import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
    import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    
    import java.util.*;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class UserModel implements UserDetails {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
    
        @NotEmpty()
        private String username;
    
        @NotEmpty(message = "Username not be Empty!")
        @Size(min = 6, max = 50)
        private String password;
    
        private List<String> authorities;
        private boolean isAccountNonExpired;
        private boolean isAccountNonLocked;
        private boolean isCredentialsNonExpired;
        private boolean isEnabled;
    
        public UserModel() {}
        public UserModel(String username, String password, List<String> authorities,boolean isAccountNonExpired, boolean isAccountNonLocked, boolean isCredentialsNonExpired, boolean isEnabled) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.authorities = authorities;
    
            this.isAccountNonExpired = isAccountNonExpired;
            this.isAccountNonLocked = isAccountNonLocked;
            this.isCredentialsNonExpired = isCredentialsNonExpired;
            this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
    
            return authorityList;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return isAccountNonExpired;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return isAccountNonLocked;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return isCredentialsNonExpired;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return isEnabled;
        }    
    }
```

**Controller** file

```java
import com.example.demo.user.UserModel;
import com.example.demo.user.UserModelRepository;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    private final UserModelRepository userModelRepository;

    public TestController(UserModelRepository userModelRepository) {
        this.userModelRepository = userModelRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showAddUserForm(UserModel userModel) {
        return "register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String addUser(@Valid UserModel userModel, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "register";
        }

        System.out.println(userModel);
        userModelRepository.save(userModel);

        model.addAttribute("users", userModelRepository.findAll());

        return "home";   // TODO - This will be executed inside of our HTML
    }

}
```

**HTML file** named: 'register.html'

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>

    <style>
        .error {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- ${user} Object -->
    <!-- *{username} Object attribute -->

    <form th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${userModel}" method="post" class="form">
        <div>

            <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" id="username" placeholder="username" name="username">
            <!-- <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errorclass="error" th:errors="*{username}" /> -->
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errorclass="error" th:errors="*{username}"> </p>

        </div>
        <div>

            <h2> Password </h2>
            <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" >
            <ul>
                <li th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('password')}" th:text="${error}" class="error">
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}">
            <ul>
                <li th:each="error : ${#fields.allErrors()}" th:text="${error}"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Add me">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Problem**
Whenever i fill in my form it always displays errors whenever i click submit. Regardless if they're filled in or not.
Why is it always displaying an error?

I'm guessing that somehow, although i'm trying to render a condition, it always turns to 'false'.
I just can't see what i'm doing wrong.

**Tutorial** i'm following: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-error-messages

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6xsA.png)

Comment: Remove `id` and `name` from the input fields. Also in your dpeendencies remove the `version` from the dependency. There are also no setters in your model object so even if you fill in a value it will never be set on the object because there simply is no way on doing that.

Comment: The ID & Name were just for debugging - and they were quite unnecessary indeed. 
Why would i want to remove the version? Could you explain?

Fixing setters solved the issue (weirdly enough, considering i had a constructor). 
But hey it solved it! 

Can you please post this as a comment so i can accept your answer?

Comment: You need to remove the version because Spring Boot manages that version. If you add a version explicitly eventually you will run into version conflicts if you upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.2/3.0.3 and this one will stick on 3.0.1, leading to (at one point) incompatible class errors etc. so unless you want to go bug hunting weird error message by all means keep the version, but you probably don't want that.

Comment: Very well written, big thanks for explaining and for solving my problem so quickly. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `UserModel` it doesn't provide setter methods and thus nop data binding will (or even can) take place.

To fix either add the setter methods **or** tell Spring to use direct field binding.

By adding the following method to your controller you can achieve direct field binding/access.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.initDirectFieldAccess();
}
```

The code above will use fields instead of properties (getter/setter pair) to do the binding. With that you can leave your `UserModel` unmodified and still have data binding applied.